# mysql date-format returns null

Tags: mysql, null, date-format

I have the following SQL query. It returns NULL for the 'invoice_date'.

```
SELECT * , fk_uid AS userId, fk_ivid AS invoice_uid, (

SELECT company
FROM tbl_users
WHERE pk_uid = userId
) AS invoice_customer, (

SELECT DATE_FORMAT( '%d/%m/%y', purchased ) AS invoice_date
FROM _invoices
WHERE invoice_uid = invoice_uid
LIMIT 1
) AS invoice_date
FROM tbl_statement_items
WHERE statement_generated = '1'
AND fk_statementId = '1'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Any help would be appriciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have inverted [date_format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) parameters order.

Comment: Thanks it didn't throw any errors when i rabn it +1, can't accept your answer for 6 mins :P